# Scrolling in Webview Progmatically

Tags: javascript, scrollview

I am having a webview which dispalys large amounbt of data. I want to scroll Webview progmatically. I know window.scrollto() method is there but ,god knows why, it is not working. Can anybody guide me step by step how to do this ? I am sure there is some minor problem. Pl. guide me.

Comment: Without a code sample it's hard to say, are you  using `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to call the javascript window.scrollto()?

Answer (score 0):

simplest possible way i am aware about is adding url?param=value#id technique. I am not sure is you are looking for this but it works nicely. This is called [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have a syntax error. Its `element.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)` :)

Sample code would be useful if you have some for us.

Is it the actual window that has a scroll or is it some element inside the window that has a scroll.

You should try to alert your x-coord and y-coord just before you call `scrollTo()` to see if there are actual values there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan & Anil, this forum is a hit due to people like u. I was out of Station so replying late. 


Actually after posting question, I came to know that Window.scrollTo() is the method for scrolling.so that prob is solved. Now my New  Question is that I am  displaying a webpage and search functionality is Implemented. All the occurences of a given word are highlited. Now i want that when i Click on next button it should scroll down to next occurence. I am aware of fragment identifier but still could not solve it. Any help will be appreciated.